# Context Floating Menu

Tags: android

I have created a Context Floating Menu like this:

[image]

I added a header too (it is not shown in this picture).
It works perfect but i want to change :

1. Background
2. Color/drawable between the header and the first item
3. The color of the header
4. And other settings

Can someone show me an example in the styles.xml file how to change some of those settings?

EDIT: To be more specific i will show my code:

Here i register my view for the context menu:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListItemView demoItem1 = (ListItemView) findViewById(R.id.demoItem1);
    registerForContextMenu(demoItem1);
}
```

Here i create and inflate the menu:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("List Actions");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Here are the options if clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.dublicate:
        return true;
    case R.id.edit:
        return true;
    case R.id.delete:
        return true;
    case R.id.rename:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the context_menu.xml :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/dublicate"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_item_dublicate">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_item_edit"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_item_delete"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/rename"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_item_rename"/>
```

Comment: It depends how did you create it.

Comment: There are many ways. All will be explained in the official [**Dialog Tutorial**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).